# How to avoid keyboard pushing layout up on Android react-native

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard

I'm facing this issue for a few months and I still can't solve it.
I have a text input at the bottom of the view that is supposed to rise up with the soft keyboard once tapped.
Instead, the whole layout is pushed up and you can't see the upper part of it.

I tried many different keyboard spacer libraries but they all just push the TextInput even higher..

Screenshots:
[Without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NXyK.png)
[With keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhoMh.png)

Here is my main View:

```
<View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'stretch',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      backgroundColor: Colors.darkBlue
    }}
  >
    {/* Header */}
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        height: 300
      }}>
      {/* Question bubble */}
      { (this.state.question && this.state.question !== '') ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                alignItems: 'stretch',
                paddingRight: QUESTION_SPEAKER_RADIUS
              }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  alignSelf: 'stretch',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                }}
            >
              <Text>
                {this.state.question}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : null
      }
    </View>
    <KeyboardInput
      style={{}}
      onClose={() => this.setState({ displayMode: DISPLAY_MODES.homeEmpty })}
      onConfirm={(text) => this.onConfirmText(text) }
    />
  </View>
```

Here is KeyboardInput:

```
<View
      style={{
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        borderColor: Colors.lime,
        borderTopWidth: 4,
        padding: 6,
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          borderRadius: 6,
          padding: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          alignItems: 'stretch',
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          placeholder={Strings.child_keyboard_placeholder}
          value={this.state.messageTextInput}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({messageTextInput: text})}
          style={{
            height: 50,
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginRight: CONFIRM_BUTTON_SIZE / 2
          }}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          numberOfLines={2}
          maxLength={70}
          autoCorrect={false}
          returnKeyType='next'
        />
      </View>
    </View>
```

Using RN 0.35 on Android.

Comment: Using the RN KeyboardAvoidingView doesn't solve it. It just pushes the TextInput higher than the keyboard

Comment: I have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the manifest, and yet it doesn't work..

Comment: If you are using expo, this can be easily solved with Expo SDK 38 and above. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/62601264/8407719

Answer (score 107):

The problem here is that you have in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize";
```

Change it to:

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**Note:** after this change you'll need run `./gradlew clean` in android folder and `react-native run-android` in your project directory

Comment: adjustPan has the wrong effect, I want the window to resize when the keyboard shows, so that the view won't be pushed out of the screen.

Comment: For those who had the same problem as me: After modifying the AndroidManifest.xml you have to re run the "react-native run-android" command.

Answer (score 24):

I tried all the solutions I could find in GitHub or stack overflow. Adding the following line of code in AndroidManifest.xml will be helpful.

I've tried this

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Sometimes it works but it misbehaves.

And then I came accross this

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

This also misbehaves
I finally combined both of them something like this and it works fine out of the box.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

And then you can use react-native KeyboardAvoidingView component.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={{ flex: 1}}
    behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : undefined}
    keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 0}
  >
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The setting must be one of the values listed in the following table, or a combination of one "state..." value plus one "adjust..." value. Setting multiple values in either group — multiple "state..." values, for example — has undefined results

Answer (score 15):

putting

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

in Manifest worked for me.

Comment: Just note that this will prevent keyboards from emitting events, [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard#addlistener)

Answer (score 13):

All the answers are good, but didn't work when using expo.

#### Managed workflow

If using expo you can use `softwareKeyboardLayoutMode` like this inside `app.json`:

```json
"android": {
  ...
  "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"
},
```

You need to be on expo version 38.0.0+

#### Bare workflow

Otherwise, modifying `AndroidManifest.xml` works:

```xml
windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: This also worked for me. I needed to upgrade expo SDK to the latest version (49) with `yarn add expo@^49.0.0`. I had version 47 before and it didn't work until I upgraded it

Answer (score 3):

Well, thanks to the React Native FB group I got a solution:
The status bar has to be not 'hidden' in order for this to work. Really weird bug..

Comment: An issue was opened - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12980

Answer (score 3):

Setting

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

on the MainActivity in AndroidManifest.xml worked for me !

However `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` **is not suggested** as it completely takes your freedom of making any design responsive to keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

In your main 'AndroidManifest.xml' file change the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`.

'android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"' covers the part of the screen where the keyboard appears and hides the content that was there previously. Scrolling may not be possible while the keyboard is active.

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` pushes the selected input field above the keyboard and allows you to scroll without pushing the entire component out of place like `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` does.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple deadly tutorials for anyone venturing into this area:

- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580
- https://medium.com/@bosung90/use-higher-order-component-in-react-native-df44e634e860

I will look very closely at the HOC solution myself shortly for this project, but for now, I just need this problem gone, which `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` did for me.

With that, the keyboard just comes up **over top** of the view. With the default resize option, every component was using `flex: 1` and justify/align `center` so the view got all kinds of mangled. Considering my view only has one input and is part of an 8 view, 8 step process, this is way too much work for me given the keyboard doesn't even go over top of the input with `adjustPan`.

But, in my opinion, the optimal solution is to use `<KeyboardAvoidingView />` in conjunction with add and remove event listeners and swapping component `styles` with some state toggles. It's the only way to get full control over the UI on both Android and iOS through both keyboard states.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is:

Define **keyboardVerticalOffset** and put everything in a **ScrollView** put **keyboardVerticalOffset={-500}**

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style = {styles.container} 
behavior="position" keyboardVerticalOffset={-550}>  

ScrollView
    TextInput
```

I tried many solutions from changing android windowsoft in XML to height of container and what not then I found this solution on [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11681#issuecomment-285941630).

Comment: why keyboardVerticalOffset 550, does it work with other devices?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but this but the above answers didn't work for me.
I tried `KeyboardAvoidingView` outside `ScrollView` with `behavior={'padding'}` as I guess `behavior={'position'}` has been messing with view. following is my code

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
   <ApplicationDetailsTabs
    initialIndex={this.state.activeTab}
    onChange={this.onTabChange}
    />
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing that problem of "how to hide TAB.Navigation while keyboard is open ,now after searching i have found that ... so do  **tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true** in your Tab.navigator  , i am sure that it will help you e.g:

```
<Tab.Navigator
screenOptions={{
tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true
....//other options
 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo put inside app.json in android section:

```
"android": {
  ...
  "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"
},
```

You need to be on expo version 38.0.0+

Answer (score -2):

I had a particular situation where the only way I could prevent this from happening was by giving the problematic TextInput a minHeight in its style.