# Screen not shifting up in 2nd tab in react-navigation-tabs toptabnavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a top tabbar created using creatematerialtoptabnavigator and it has two screens.
The screens are having textinput in registration form.

The screen moves up as usual when the keyboard is visible on the first tab but it doesn't on the 2nd tab.
If i interchange the screens the 2nd screen which is now the first screen moves the screen up and the next screen doesn't move the screen.

Here is a below example gif:-

https://gifyu.com/image/kXVB

Comment: post some code and let us know what you have already tried to fix it

Comment: Exactly , I was also about to say d same.

Comment: Why not try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57442705/10398005

Answer (score 0):

I can't say the exact solution, without checking the code snippets, but i hope this would help you.
You should wrap the whole input fields with the keyboard-aware-scroll-view or keyboard avoid view or similar.
pls refer this for more info..
https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view