# View moves out of the screen when Text Input is focused used on Bottom Sheet in React Native for Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm using the library - 
https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet

I'm using a `TextInput` on this bottom sheet. And now when the Text Input is focused or typed in, the bottom sheet should remain at the same position. It works fine for iOS, shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

And when I focus the Text Input on Android, the bottom sheet moves up along with the keyboard, shown in below 2 screenshots.

(Bottom Sheet in Android not focused)

[image]

(Bottom Sheet in Android focused)

[image]

I've also tried wrapping my bottom sheet inside `KeyboardAvoidingView` and its props accordingly but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem in my project using **Expo Kit 38**

Just add this to your app.json file:

```
"android": {
  "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"
}
```

Here’s how to upgrade your app to Expo SDK 38.0.0 from 37.0.0:

1. Update expo-cli by running `npm i -g expo-cli`
2. Run `expo upgrade` in your project directory

You may want to check the [documentation](https://dev.to/expo/expo-sdk-38-is-now-available-5aa0) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in AndroidManifest.xml worked! :D

Comment: I am using expo, any ideas?

Comment: @mleister no I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Set the device screen `height` to your `BottomSheet`'s parent container.
Example code:

```js
import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet'
import { View as Container, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window') // Magic value.


const Screen = () => (
  <Container style={{ height }}>
    {/* Your screen content here */}
    <BottomSheet {...yourBottomSheetParams} />
  </Container>
)

export default Screen
```

1. Works for Expo Managed Workflow projects. While setting the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` is not possible there.
2. `height: 100%` did not work for me (was suggested here on GitHub [Bottom Sheet moves up along with Keyboard in Android and not iOS #203](https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet/issues/203)).