# How to add properties in AndroidManifest in react native app built with expo?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-manifest

I am trying to build a basic react native app with expo...The problem I am facing is that all the components are getting lifted when i try using the keyboard..
I searched for my problem on stack overflow and i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840555/how-to-avoid-keyboard-pushing-layout-up-on-android-react-native) which suggests changing

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml to this:

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

But the problem is that I can't find AndroidManifest.xml in my expo react native app... How and where should I add this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add it in app.json file or app.config.json under expo under android

read about `softwarekeyboardlayoutmode` in configratation file [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#softwarekeyboardlayoutmode)

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "your app name",
    ...
    "android": {
      ...
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode" : "pan"
    }
  }
}
```